# how do i display data from a nested form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a nested models form which feeds two tables. I have nested my Places fields within my Posts form. How do I display the nested data in my show.html.erb file?

```
<h1>My Update</h1><br>
<p>my status: <%= @post.status %></p>
<p>this is the upload: <%= link_to @post.upload, @post.upload %></p>
 <p><%= @place.address %></p>
```

I get a "NoMethodError in Posts#show" error on the last line.

It says "undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass"

If you want to see all the code, I just pushed to github. http://bit.ly/1dsu94Y

Comment: The error is saying `@place` is nil.  Have you double checked your controller action that renders this view?

Comment: I added `code @place = Place.find params[:id]` into the show method. It looks like my form isn't populating the Places table in the database...

Comment: your routes.rb is also invalid, for nested resource you should make posts resource inside place resource block, put do end around post resource

Comment: Does this mean I need to nest my Post params in my Form under Place View? That would be the opposite of what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
 <p><%= @place.address %></p>
```

**With**

```
 <p><%= @post.place.address %></p>
```

As you have not set `@place` instance variable, you are getting the error.
Looking at your code, I see that you have `1-M` relationship between `Place` and `Post` model.
So, in order to display the `address` of a `place` to which a particular `post` belongs to, you can do it as mentioned above.

Comment: @siriusparis Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load the @place instance variable in your [PostsController#show method](https://github.com/austinsamsel/donde/blob/master/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb). Once you load that in the show method, however you need to do it based on your app's data, models, etc., you will no longer receive the error.

Comment: Ok - I added in `code @place = Place.pluck params[:address]`

Comment: It looks like my form isn't saving the address to the Places table... so I also just added `code @post.place = Place.new params[:address]` in the PostsController#create method